# Add the values of items with same name in the table

Tags: sqlite, android-studio

I have heater, lamp, tv and so on in a table. the table records their details. There will be some items with more than one entry. such as below.

---

device    watt     watt used

heater    220        2000

heater    220        2000

heater    220        2500

tv        1000       3000

tv        1000       5000

---

I wan to total up all watt used for heater and tv respectively for display in the pie chart, such as heater=6500 W, tv=8000 W.
Also, there are many more items that can be added. so how can i do this so that it total up the watt used of every items in the list only.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need a SQL Statement? I don't know SQLite, but this would be a standard SQL statement that does the job. Of course I don't know your table and column names, since you didn't post them.

```
SELECT id, device, SUM(watt_used)
FROM powertable
GROUP BY id, device
```

Edit: Added an id column.

Comment: Thanks. It works. One more question. If I wan to add another column that state their ID, where the ones entered first will have number1, follwed by 2, etc according to the device name. example, heater 1, heater 2, heater 3, tv1, tv2. How should the query be?

Comment: I have amended my SQL. But I would recommend that you look for an SQL tutorial or a "SQL for Beginners" Book, because the language is too complex to learn it by SO Questions :)